# How to do Vim mapping on help page only

Tags: vim

I would like to go-to a tag when pressing enter (instead of clicking with the mouse when `mouse=a`) or pressing `ctrl-]`, which is a bit of a stretch for me. Is it possible to do the mapping in the help section only, such as:

```
:nnoremap *help* <CR> <C-]>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do exactly that in [an ftplugin for `:help` files](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/86c4965c7e31530a673b128c40fdf3dfe9350499/links/vim/after/ftplugin/help.vim#L15): put your mapping in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/help.vim` and use `<buffer>`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <C-]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a [buffer-local mapping](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-local) when a help file is loaded:

```
:autocmd BufReadPost $VIMRUNTIME/doc/help*.txt nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <C-]>
```

Comment: thanks can you please explain the difference between this approach and the one from @Kent, where it creates a basic mapping (without `BufReadPost filter` but instead using FileType?)

Comment: Not much difference. I use `help*.txt` to recognize help files, the other answers use filetype (which is perhaps more correct).

Answer (score 1):

If the "help page" you meant is vim doc/help, they have `ft=help`. You can verify it by `:echo &ft` or `:set ft?`.

Then it is easy if you want to create mapping only for those filetypes. You can do it using autocommand:

```
autocmd FileType help map....
```

If you want it to be buffer local mapping, you add `<buffer>` in mapping.

Comment: thanks, could you very briefly describe the difference between this approach and the approach by `phd`, using a Filter instead of FileType?

Comment: @David542 the difference is obvious :D , the other answer checks the file path and name pattern. This answer checks the ft. If you've some plugin installed in your $HOME and open the help doc of the plugin, this answer will work but the other not.